# Assigning $m$ balls to $n$ buckets - recursive algorithm

Tags: recursion, balls-and-bins

I came across the following problem and the answer to that problem:

> Given $m$ balls and $n$ bins, find out how many ways to assign the balls to the bins. Notice the bins have no order: for example, $(1,2,3)$ and $(3,2,1)$ are considered the same.
>
> As an example, if $m = 3$ and $n = 2$, you should return 2, since there are two possibilities: $(1,2)$ and $(3,0)$.

Here is a recurrence which seems to work:
$$
f(m,n) =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } m = 0 \text{ or } n = 1 \\
f(m,m) & \text{if } n > m \\
f(m,n-1) + f(m-n, n) & \text{if } 1 < n \leq m
\end{cases}
$$

This solution seem to work. However I don't understand how $f(m,n-1) + f(m-n,n)$ works. Why is it considering $m-n$ balls into $n$ bins?

Answer (score 1):

An assignment of balls into $n$ bins falls into either one of the following two cases.

- Every bin has as last one ball. So let us assign one ball to each bin first. What remains to do is to assign the remaining balls to the bins.
- Otherwise. That is, there is at least one bin that has no ball. This case is the same as assigning all balls into $n-1$ bins.

**Exercise.** Verify that we are counting without duplicates and without missing assignment.